# Continuity of translation for p=infinite

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

For $f\in L^p$, $1\leq p<\infty$, the property of continuity of translation holds:
$$\lim_{|x|\to 0}\|f_x-f\|_p=0,$$
where
$$f_x(y):=f(x+y).$$
When $p=\infty$, is continuity of translation still true? If not, can you give a counterexample?

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $f = \chi_{[0,1]}$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$,
$$
\|f_x -f\| = \|\chi_{[-x,1-x]} - \chi_{[0,1]}\| = 1
$$